# Piping the output of ls or tree to less loses colors?

Tags: ls, less

`tree` and `ls` can distinct file types by coloring filenames differently.

`tree` and `ls` often output a long list of files (including directories), so I pipe the stdout output to `less`.

But `less` doesn't preserve the colors. How can we make it show colors, or some alternative ways?

Just saw the linked list, but piping to `less -R` or `less -r` doesn't work. My OS is Ubuntu 12.04. `less` is Version 444: 09 Jun 2011.

Comment: @JosephR. the other question is half-related but not a duplicate. Here we're talking `ls` (not `tree`) for which some implementations need to be told to force color output when the output doesn't go to a terminal (in addition to `less -R` being needed)

Comment: Have you tried `tree -C | less -R`? The `-C` option is tree's equivalent of less's `--color=always`, I think (at least it works for me, on Ubuntu 12.04).

Comment: @steeldriver thanks. it works. `tree` with and without `-C` alone always output in colors, but why are they different when used with `less`?

Comment: @Tim 2 reasons: 1. `less` removes the colors by default unless you give it the `-R` option, which tells it to leave it in, and 2. `tree` and `ls` and other programs usually turn coloring off when they detect their output is going to another program (like `less`) instead of directly to your terminal, unless you force the coloring on with `-C` or `--color=always`.

Comment: What is this linked list you write about?

Comment: about files and subdirectories. @Anthon

Answer (score 19):

I'm going to assume you're using `ls --color=auto`, which tells `ls` to use color in 'automatic' mode. 'Automatic' mode tells `ls` to see if STDOUT is a terminal, and if so, use color, otherwise don't use color. When you pipe `ls` into `less`, STDOUT is not a terminal, it's connected to STDIN of `less`, which is a normal pipe.

The solution, use `ls --color` or `ls --color=always`.

However now this leads to another potential issue. Depending on your `less`, it may not show the color, but show the escape codes instead. The solution is to use `less -R`. This tells `less` to pass through the escape codes for ANSI color escapes. You don't want to use `-r` as this will cause problems with long lines that wrap around, as less doesn't properly calculate line length.

So full solution:

```
ls --color | less -R
```

Similarly for `tree`:

```
tree -C | less -R
```